# how to change my android app's window appearance in apps list when my app is in background?

Tags: android, android-layout, onresume, onpause, background-foreground

I'll try to explain my question:

I have an app developed by me, that is now open on my android device with some activity that contains some data.

I want to **hide this data if my app goes to background** and I have some other apps open and looking on the open apps list.

Is there any way to change current activity's layout (I have many activities) when the app goes to background? For example to blur it or just show some default layout/image instead of current activity with the real data that I have?

[image]

viewing open apps

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `onPause()` methode cause it's the last executed method before the application goes background

Comment: How can I check for each possible activity in my app that onPause() event is going to background because of a new opened app, and not just another activity of my app was opened?

Answer (score 0):

and you can disable thumbnail on the activity containing sensitive data by adding `FLAG_SECURE` to your window:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Or exclude it from recents in the manifest

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think FLAG_SECURE also causes some issues like blocking screenshots in my app?

Comment: Yes it does, I believe its only for that activity though but if you dont want it shown in recents why would you still want to be able to take a screenshot of that info?

Comment: I would like to have an option of taking screenshots when the app is active, and only when another app is opened and my app goes to foreground, I want to hide the displayed data. It's relevant only for the case when multiple apps are opened and the current app is some other app. Like in the attached screenshot